# How to add extra model/view/controller/table to custom MVC component as addon/extension

Tags: joomla

I've created an MVC Component for Joomla 3.X that supports a basic image gallery, slideshow manager and product catalog to be installed on the websites of my clients. However, clients have been frequently saying they don't want/need all three of the options, and will only use one or two of the three. So to clear up clutter and make it easier on clients, I delete the unwanted options either pre-install or post-install.

After spending a while dealing with this issue, it occurred to me that it may just be easier/faster to install only the base structural files with the initial install zip, and then later install the desired options.

ie:

1. Install com_mycustom.zip for base files used regardless of what options will later be installed
2. Install com_mycustom_*optionname*Addon.zip for the controller/model/table/view for that option

Is something like this possible in Joomla? I've looked through their documentation, and haven't really found anything pertaining to something like this.

Comment: Each next installer file can use the upgrade method and will contain all the extra required files for the additional features.

Comment: Also there is a dedicated Joomla site in StackExchange for Joomla Administration and Development. Check there: [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).